# How to call a Button press Event even with the press of the Enter key on keyboard

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

the following is the Markup of my page based on a master page. its a log in page with a default login control.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2 style="text-align:center; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">
    Log In
</h2>
<p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;margin-left: 90px;margin-right: 90px;">
    Please enter your username and password.<br />
    If you don't have an account, please contact the site administrator to set up 
    your account.
</p>
<div style="margin-left:0px;">


<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <span class="failureNotification">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </span>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
        <div class="accountInfo">
            <fieldset class="login">
                <legend style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">Account Information</legend>
                <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User ID:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" Width="176px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User ID is required." ToolTip="User ID field is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" 
                        TextMode="Password" Width="176px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>

            <p class="submitButton">
                &nbsp;<asp:Panel ID="LoginPanel" runat="server"  DefaultButton="LoginButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                    ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" onclick="LoginButton_Click"/>
            </asp:Panel>
                <p>
                </p>
            </p>

        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>


</div>
```

I wish to know how to let the login buttons click even fire when the users press enter on the keyboard.

Do i have to do the codeing in the .cs page or it can be done in the markup?
Please help

Page update with adding javascript in the master page body tag

```
<body onload="updateClock(); setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )" onkeypress="checkenter();">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkenter() 
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) 
        { //if they pressed enter key then..
            document.formname.LoginButton.focus();

        }
    }
</script>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
```

LogIn click event action

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //assign textbox items to string objects
        userIDStr = LoginUser.UserName.ToString();
        pwrdStr = LoginUser.Password.ToString();

        //SQL connection string

        string strConn;
        strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSSQL3ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);



        //SqlDataSource CSMDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
        // CSMDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSSQL3ConnectionString"].ToString();


        //SQL select statement for comparison

        string sqlUserData;
        sqlUserData = "SELECT UserID, UserPassword, UserName, UserType FROM Users";
        sqlUserData += " WHERE (UserID ='" + userIDStr + "')";
        sqlUserData += " AND (UserPassword ='" + pwrdStr + "')";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlUserData, Conn);
        SqlDataReader rdr;
        string usrdesc;
        string Uname;


        try
        {

            //string CurrentData;
            //CurrentData = (string)com.ExecuteScalar();
            Conn.Open();
            rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Read();
            usrdesc = (string)rdr["UserType"];
            Uname = (string)rdr["UserName"];


            LoginUser.UserName = Uname.ToString();

            rdr.Close();
            Session["userID"] = userIDStr;
            Session["userType"] = usrdesc;


            if (usrdesc.ToLower() == "administrator")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Uname, false);
                Response.Redirect("~/CaseAdminPage.aspx"/*?adminID=" + userIDStr*/, false);

            }
            else if (usrdesc.ToLower() == "manager")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Uname, false);
                Response.Redirect("~/ManagerPage.aspx"/*?mgrID=" + userIDStr*/, false);
            }
            else if (usrdesc.ToLower() == "investigator")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Uname, false);
                Response.Redirect("~/Investigator.aspx"/*?investigatorID=" + userIDStr*/, false);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", false);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string script = "<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>";
        }
        finally
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Promise to accept as answer if answered.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you - but this is a Javascript problem (as it all happens in the browser). You're after something like Javascript's onkeypress. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614856/how-to-submit-a-form-onkeypress-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the div surrounding your login control to an `<asp:Panel>` control. Then set the DefaultButton property to LoginButton:

```
<asp:Panel ID="LoginPanel" runat="server" style="margin-left:0px;" DefaultButton="LoginButton">

    ....

</asp:Panel>
```

EDIT: code snippet update

```
    <!-- Notice I've changed the <div class="accountInfo"> with the
         asp panel to encompass the the textbox controls and the login button -->
    <asp:Panel CssClass="accountInfo" ID="LoginPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="LoginButton">
        <fieldset class="login">
            <legend style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">Account Information</legend>
            <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">
                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User ID:</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" Width="176px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User ID is required." ToolTip="User ID field is required." 
                     ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">
                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" 
                    TextMode="Password" Width="176px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                     ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>

        <p class="submitButton">
            &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" onclick="LoginButton_Click"/>

            <p>
            </p>
        </p>

    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: @Joel---i got the following error(The DefaultButton of 'LoginPanel' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl.) What is going wrong?

Comment: @Selase - Based on the code snippet above that error doesn't really make sense. The `<asp:Button>` control definitely implements IButtonControl. I've used it many times before. I wonder if it's because the LoginButton is inside your `<LayoutTemplate>`. Perhaps if you move the `<asp:Panel>` inside the `<LayoutTemplate>` it will have a more direct effect.

Comment: @ Joe-- So would this work?  <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Panel ID="LoginPanel" runat="server" ;" DefaultButton="LoginButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                        ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" onclick="LoginButton_Click"/>
                </asp:Panel>
                </p>

Comment: @Selase - The `<asp:Panel>` needs to surround your TextBoxes in order to be effective.

Comment: @Joe -- It appears to post back but the form does not log in...it seems nothing happens... probably because the clickevent doesnt fire?

Comment: @Selase - The click event should definitely be firing if the enter key generates a postback. Have you placed debug marks on the click event in the code behind?

Comment: @Joe---I dont think so...I have updated my question with the code behind of the login click event. Please check and advise as to how to attach the debug feature...

Comment: @Selase - I've added a code snippet to my answer. When you are in Visual Studio and you click the run button, it will automatically attach a debugger to the code. However, in your code behind you need to click in the far left grey area on the `protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` line to generate a line-break. Then you can step through the code line by line. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @Joe---You are a just too great...hahaha:D.. it worked this time after i followed your edit...

Answer (score 2):

Have you come across this article?

The defaultbutton attribute may be just what your looking for.

http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/04/12/74951.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: I think using java script is better to do this, but that is just my opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

One way I think you can get it to work is by using JavaScript

```
<body onkeypress="checkenter();" >


<script language="javascript">
function checkenter() {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { //if they pressed enter key then..
    document.formname.LoginButton.focus();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: After the focus is achieved, the btn click event is automatically fired.

Comment: @ Voo Thanks...I have a feeling this would work... but can i just use document.formname.LoginButton.focus(); or they are a representation of some controls or contents on my page? and should the script be in the body tag or in the head of the master page? the log in control is on the login page that is based on the master page though..

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one submit button you can put an `onsubmit` handler in the form tag. I don't really know how to do that with your ASP code, but hopefully you do.